# Can a user manually clean chrome.storage.local in Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building an extension that is heavily dependent on the local storage, and I want to be absolutely sure that a user will not clean it.

I know that I can use `chrome.storage.local.clear()` to clear it, but is there any other way that the user can clean it manually?

Comment: Just like anything else stored locally, the user can clear it via devtools. In this case by opening devtools of any extension page and typing chrome.storage.local.clear() or using an extension like Storage Area Explorer.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I was trying to find a way to do it via the settings GUI, something like clear browser history or cookies. It seems that there is no such functionality for extensions at the moment, other than reinstalling the extension.